# Size Option in MIT Poker Package?

Tags: packages, package-options

I'm using Poker MIT Package, and I already know that there is the command

```
\setkeys{poker}{option=value[,option=value]}
```

for setting up some options. In the package documentation, a "size" option is referred but no possible values for this option are presented. I tried `huge`, `scriptsize` and numeric values but I always got error messages. Can anyone help?

Comment: Welcome to TeX:SE! You will hare more chances for an answer, if You will provide an document example  with your command.

Comment: Do you mean this poker package? http://web.mit.edu/foley/games/Arcadia/sr/poker/poker.sty

Comment: I would recommend using the actively-maintained [pst-poker](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/pst-poker), which is derived from the MIT poker package. Its documentation explains how to scale cards